# Child theme showing a blank page

Tags: child-theme

I just created a child theme and activated it.But when I visit the page,it's completely blank.

In the display is the themes folder where I have my parent theme and the child,then below is the site details from the parent style.css which I simply copied and pasted to the child stylesheet.

[image]

functions.php looks like this:

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

As the photo shows,the theme is active.

[image]

How can I create a child theme and make it visible as the parent theme?

This is what I see when I load the page and try to inspect:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think you've nothing in the `index.php` file. So what is happening that the child theme is calling the child theme's `index.php` over parent theme's `index.php`. And you have nothing on `index.php`. So the site is showing nothing. Delete the child theme's `index.php`. You'll see the site live.

Comment: @the_dramatist.No. Basically,the child theme is active,all I want is to be able to view the site when I click on visit site.

Comment: **How can I create a child theme and make it visible as the parent theme?**  I though you need this question answer.

Comment: the child theme is created and activated as you can see from the photo. The problem is that when I visit the site, I don't see any content.And when I inspect the element,there is nothing as well

Comment: check the updated answer.

Comment: index.php deleted.But page is still blank

Comment: Press **Ctrl+R** to refresh. Then see and let me know. Better if you add a screenshot of your blank page.

Comment: just updated my question so you can see the blank page. And also you can see that there is no content when I inspect.

Comment: In your `wp-config.php` make `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`. Then refresh and if you see any error message please give it to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47376/discussion-between-the-dramatist-and-wosley-alarico).

Answer (score 1):

---

```
*
 Theme Name:   Twenty Fifteen Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  Twenty Fifteen Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     twentyfifteen
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  twenty-fifteen-child
*/
```

---

See carefully wordpress coding standard. You have forgot define **Template** of your parents theme. Please define **Template** of your parent theme and then see.
Hope this will help!